# Стилистика "15-е число"

Tags: грамотная-речь, стилистика

Можно ли сказать, например, "15-е число: день открытых дверей в музыкальной школе"? Или и так ясно, что 15 — это число, и выходит масло масляное (ну, как говорить "в апреле месяце"). Но если "15-е число" — это ошибка, то как говорить верно?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Можно ли сказать, например, "15-ое число: день открытых дверей в музыкальной школе"?*

Да, **сказать** так — можно, но **писать** — нельзя!

1. Буквенное наращение после числительного должно быть таким: ***15-е*** число.
2. Если это список мероприятий, то после слова "число" лучше поставить тире:

1-е число — родительское собрание;
...
15-е число — день открытых дверей.

Например:
15-е число – последний день уплаты страховых взносов;
15-е число 8-го лунного месяца.

[**Наращение в порядковых числительных**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/87-rubric-99)

Comment: Спасибо вам, а я и забыла, что правильно "15-е", а не "15-ое". Спрашивала об одном, а открыла для себя совсем другое. Спасибо большое! А по поводу тире. Т.е. постановка двоеточия тоже будет именно ошибкой в этом примере? Или все-таки и двоеточие возможно?

Comment: Двоеточие обычно предполагает перечисление. 15-ое число: день открытых дверей в музыкальной школе; концерт ансамбля; поздравление лауреатов...(Как пример.) Если оформлять **красиво**, то лучше все-таки тире.

Comment: Еще раз спасибо вам за помощь! Спасибо, что всё разъяснили.

Comment: Строго говоря, День открытых дверей - мероприятие, поэтому лучше использовать прописную букву.

Comment: А вот "1-е число — родительское собрание" кажестя мне неудачным; родительское собрание — не весь день. Корректнее: 1-го числа — родительское собрание.

Answer (score 2):

В каком случае именно так — 15-е число (не называя имени месяца) — и следует говорить? Когда это актуально, т. е. когда месяц является текущим. Напротив, будет противоестественно о предстоящих (оставшихся) днях месяца, напоминать о его названии. Название опускают, вставляя не менее информативные слова: *в 20-х числах* (этого, или следующего) *месяца*.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Пример из Нацкорпуса: Так что вполне возможно, что дальнейшее повышение курса можно ожидать только после выплат по НДС 20-го числа. [Интервенции Центробанка (2002) // «Финансовая Россия», 2002.09.19]

Answer (score 1):

Такое сочетание абсолютно корректно. Вот из словаря.

**Число - день месяца в порядковом ряду других дней. В первых числах августа. Какое сегодня ч.?**

Хотя в разговорной речи слово "число" часто опускается.

Comment: Сержик, падежное наращение абсолютно некорректно.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: Да, конечно. Но я отвечал на вопрос о корректности самого выражения. А окончание и не заметил.

Comment: @GalinaAvanesova Окончание — не слон!